# automatic update installation WP 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

is it possible to install  newest app version automaticly while the app is not in the windows store?

Eg. I have server that has installation files and when app detects that it's out of date it downloads newer version and installs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to bypass *Windows Store* on normal device unless you are writing a [Company app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx).

Your app has to pass certification, then it's published and automatically available for update through the Store.

The only other ways to deploy the apps is app deployment tool, but this only concerns registered phone, during developement.

Comment: A CompanyApp is exactly what i am looking for! :) Thnaks so much i am new to winrt development